# object has no attribute 'append' in python while using a imported file

Tags: python-3.x

I keep getting an attribute error with this code.  Does anyone have any ideas why this might be the case?  I know 'str' cannot be appended but I am trying to append the list... any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
elif choice == "1":
    i=0
    eval_type = open("eval_type.txt", "r+")
    for line in eval_type:
        i+=1
        new_eval = input("What do you want to call the new evaluation?")
        points = input("How many points is this type worth?")
        if new_eval in line:
            print("\n", new_eval, "already exists.")
        else:
            eval_type.append(new_eval)
            print (new_eval, "has been added.")
    eval_type.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval_type` in your snippet is not a list; its actually a `file` type; which you cannot append to.

```
>>> x = open('test.txt','w')
>>> type(x)
<type 'file'>
```

You should initialize an empty list before the `for` loop and use that instead.